# Code uses a switch function to process messages separately, how can I use data from 2 messages?

Tags: c++, qt

So at work I inherited a massive project taking 1553 messages from an airplane and translating them to a completely different message type. My problem is that I need to use the data from 2 different messages, which are processed completely separately, together.

This is how I inherited it: there's a completely different process for processing the 2Rx message (which has the "plane altitude" data) and the 17Rx message (which has the "structure altitude" data).

I tried to simplify as much of the code that's relevant as possible, but this is the first experience I've had with coding and I've had no programming education, so please tell me if there's something I can do to make it more clear (for example I don't fully understand the Process1553 function).

My job is to do the actual conversions: in my example the altitude data for both the plane and a ground structure is being received in meters and needs to be sent out as feet. However, I ALSO need to send out data comparing the 2 altitudes (well, I'm actually converting Lat/Long/Alt to North/East/Down, but for simplicity let's just say I need the difference in altitudes of the plane and the structure).

```
void AirplaneComm::Process1553()
{
    M1553RawMsgClass *currentMessage;

    //check for new messages
    while(incomingMessages->size()>0)
    {
        //grab the message from the top of the stack
        currentMessage=(M1553RawMsgClass*)incomingMessages->front();

        //pop the stack
        incomingMessages->pop_front();

        //We are only interested in R messages
        if(currentMessage->MessageType()==M1553RawMsgClass::RECEIVE_MSG)
        {
            M1553RxMsgClass newRxMessage(*currentMessage);

            switch (newRxMessage.RxMsgType())
            {
               case M1553RxMsgClass::RX_2: {
                  ProcessRx2Msg(newRxMessage);
                  break;}

               // .... more messages

               case M1553RxMsgClass::RX_17: {
                  ProcessRx17Msg(newRxMessage);
                  break;}

               default:
                 // No processing for this message
                 break;

             }
         }

        //clean up
        if(currentMessage)
        {
            delete currentMessage;
        }

    }
}

void AirplaneComm::ProcessRx2Msg(M1553RxMsgClass incoming2Rmessage)
{
    M1760Rx2MsgClass newMessage(incoming2Rmessage);                     //M1760 classes "get" data from
                                                                        //the 1553 messages and "set"
                                                                        //it to send as serial
    
    WordType platformAltitudeMeters = newMessage.GetPlatAltitude();     //received altitude in meters
    double platformAltitudeFeet = platformAltitudeMeters * 3.2808;      //converted to feet
    mSerial.SetPlatAltitude(platformAltitudeFeet);                      //sets the altitude info
}

void AirplaneComm::ProcessRx17Msg(M1553RxMsgClass incoming17Rmessage)
{
    M1760Rx17MsgClass newMessage(incoming17Rmessage);
    
    WordType structureAltitudeMeters = newMessage.GetStructAltitude();  //received altitude in meters
    double structureAltitudeFeet = structureAltitudeMeters * 3.2808;    //converted to feet
    mSerial.SetStructAltitude(structureAltitudeFeet);                   //sets the altitude info
}
```

So as far as I can tell, the "switch" function takes each "case" individually. I tried creating a new 2Rx AND 17Rx process ("ProcessRx2MsgRx17Msg") assigning those messages (Rx2Msg, Rx17Msg) to variables I declared in each "case":

```
            switch (newRxMessage.RxMsgType())
            {
               case M1553RxMsgClass::RX_2: 
                  ProcessRx2Msg(newRxMessage);
                  M1553RxMsgClass Rx2Msg;                //M1553RxMsgClass is a variable type taking
                  Rx2Msg = newRxMessage;                 //the whole message
                break;}

               case M1553RxMsgClass::RX_17: 
                  ProcessRx17Msg(newRxMessage);
                  M1553RxMsgClass Rx17Msg = newRxMessage;
                  break;

               default:
                 // No processing for this message
                 break;                
                
               ProcessRx2MsgRx17Msg(Rx2Msg, Rx17Msg);
             }
```

but when I did that, it claimed that I was jumping switch labels. I get that this means they are in the same "scope" (ok, I googled it) but when I put brackets around each "case":

```
               case M1553RxMsgClass::RX_2: {
                  ProcessRx2Msg(newRxMessage);
                  M1553RxMsgClass Rx2Msg;
                  Rx2Msg = newRxMessage;
                break;}

               case M1553RxMsgClass::RX_17: {
                  ProcessRx17Msg(newRxMessage);
                  M1553RxMsgClass Rx17Msg = newRxMessage;
                  break;}

               default:
                 // No processing for this message
                 break;                
                
               ProcessRx2MsgRx17Msg(Rx2Msg, Rx17Msg);
             }
```

but then my ProcessRx2MsgRx17Msg doesn't recognize "Rx2Msg" or "Rx17Msg".

I also considered making "ProcessRx2Msg" a function that could return a value instead of a void function so that I could use it in "ProcessRx17Msg", but I actually need multiple variables from each message (latitude, longitude, and altitude).

So, is it even possible to accomplish what I want with the way it's set up since I inherited it? Also, sorry if I used the wrong terms for certain things.

EDIT: Thank you JarMan and SoronelHaetir. This is how I ended up getting it to work:

```
void AirplaneComm::Process1553()
{

    M1553RawMsgClass *currentMessage;

    static M1553RxMsgClass Rx2Msg, Rx17Msg;

    //check for new messages
    while(incomingMessages->size()>0)
    {
        //grab the message from the top of the stack
        currentMessage=(M1553RawMsgClass*)incomingMessages->front();

        //pop the stack
        incomingMessages->pop_front();

        //We are only interested in R messages
        if(currentMessage->MessageType()==M1553RawMsgClass::RECEIVE_MSG)
        {
            M1553RxMsgClass newRxMessage(*currentMessage);

            switch (newRxMessage.RxMsgType())
            {
               case M1553RxMsgClass::RX_2:
                  ProcessRx2Msg(newRxMessage);
                  Rx2Msg = newRxMessage;
                break;

               // .... more messages

               case M1553RxMsgClass::RX_17:
                  ProcessRx17Msg(newRxMessage);
                  Rx17Msg = newRxMessage;
                  ProcessRx2MsgRx17Msg(Rx2Msg, Rx17Msg);
                  break;

               default:
                 // No processing for this message
                 break;

             }
         }

        //clean up
        if(currentMessage)
        {
            delete currentMessage;
        }

    }
}
```

Then, I was able to use `ProcessRx2MsgRx17Msg` to convert the airplane geodetic data from `Rx2` AND the structure geodetic data from `Rx17` to North/East/Down coordinates.

Comment: Your scope problem can be fixed by declaring your `Rx2Msg` and `Rx17Msg` variables outside the switch statement. But you don't want to call the `ProcessRx2MsgRx17Msg()` function unless you actually have data in both of those variables.

Comment: Thank you, are you saying that I can declare the variables outside the switch statement and then assign them within their "case"? If I do this, will the value still be assigned to those variables by the time "ProcessRx2MsgRx17Msg()" is called?

Comment: Yes, but really they probably need to be declared outside the `while` loop so they stay in scope through each iteration.

Comment: Oh ok, that's really helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you need to process data from multiple messages you will have to alter the earlier message processing to save the needed data somewhere then when the later message comes in refer to both the later message parameters as well as the saved message parameters from the earlier message(s). The saved data will need a lifetime longer than the single function call (whether you make it static to the message processing function or global is up to the design choices your organization uses).

Comment: Thank you! So, how to I "save the needed data" from that message processing? Sorry if my question is vague, I'm under the impression that you can't use data from one function in another one?